# Can someone help me fix this program

Tags: java, calendar

I have to create the program so that I can input 3 letters plus a year like *"jan1999"* and display the calendar.

The program must:

> 1. Prompt the user for a specific month with a meaningful message.
> 2. If the input value is a valid date (i.e. 3 characters designating the desired month (i.e. JAN, FEB, ..., in any combination of lower and
>      upper case letters, followed by a space and an integer between 1900
>      and 2099), then the calendar for the given date must be displayed
> 3. (or 2BIS) If the input value is not a valid date, the user must be informed that date was not acceptable, and then be prompted again for
>      another date. If more than three consecutive erroneous dates are
>      given, the program must be terminated with an appropriate error
>      message.

```
package assignment.pkg2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment2 {
    public static int getMonthNumber(String s) {
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("jan")) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("feb")) {
            return 2;
        }
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("mar")) {
            return 3;
        }
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("apr")) {
            return 4;
        }
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("may")) {
            return 5;
        }
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("jun")) {
            return 6;
        }
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("jul")) {
            return 7;
        }
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("aug")) {
            return 8;
        }
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("sep")) {
            return 9;
        }
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("oct")) {
            return 10;
        }
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("nov")) {
            return 11;
        }
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("dec")) {
            return 12;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not valid month!");
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        int month = 0;
        int s = getDaysIn(month, year);
        return year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
    }

    public static int getDaysIn(int month, int year) {
        switch (month) {
            case 1:
                return 31;
            case 2:
                if (isLeapYear(month)) {
                    return 29;
                } else {
                    return 28;
                }
            case 3:
                return 31;
            case 4:
                return 30;
            case 5:
                return 31;
            case 6:
                return 30;
            case 7:
                return 31;
            case 8:
                return 31;
            case 9:
                return 30;
            case 10:
                return 31;
            case 11:
                return 30;
            case 12:
                return 31;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }

    public static String getMonthName(int month) {
        switch (month) {
            case 1:
                return "January";
            case 2:
                return "February";
            case 3:
                return "March";
            case 4:
                return "April";
            case 5:
                return "May";
            case 6:
                return "June";
            case 7:
                return "July";
            case 8:
                return "August";
            case 9:
                return "September";
            case 10:
                return "October";
            case 11:
                return "November";
            case 12:
                return "December";
            default:
                return "Invalid month.";
        }
    }

    public static int getStartDay(int month, int year) {
        int days = 0;
        for (int i = 1900; i < year; i++) {
            days = days + 365;
            if (isLeapYear(i)) {
                days = days + 1;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < month; i++) {
            days = days + getDaysIn(month, year);
        }
        int startday = (days + 1) % 7 + 1;
        return startday;
    }

    public static void displayCalendar(int month, int year) {
        String monthName = getMonthName(month);
        int startDay = getStartDay(month, year);
        int monthDays = getDaysIn(month, year);

        System.out.println("   Sun   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri   Sat");
        int weekDay = startDay - 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= startDay; i = i + 1) {
            System.out.print("    ");
        }
        for (int x = 1; x <= monthDays; x++) {
            weekDay = weekDay + 1;
            if (weekDay > 7) {
                System.out.println();
                weekDay = 1;
            }
            System.out.format("   %3d", x);
        }
        if (weekDay > 7) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Give the first three letters of a month and enter the year: ");
        String month, year;
        month = c.next();
        year = c.next();
        int yearno = Integer.parseInt(year);
        int monthno = getMonthNumber(month);
        displayCalendar(monthno, yearno);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue? y/n ");
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to read up on DateFormat/SimpleDateFormat

Comment: It will reduce the size of your code since it can validate your jan1999 at for validity. The date/time functions contain more interesting things like the Calendar class....

Comment: "some months"? Please ask *specific* question. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Most of the code is easy, the trick is in validating the input as a valid date in the specified format. You can do that with the YearMonth class. Then you can create a Calendar class from that.

If you're using Java 8, try this:

```
    String myInputString = null;

    try
    {
       BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       myInputString = bufferRead.readLine();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print(e);
    }

    YearMonth myYM = null;
    Calendar calendar = null;

    try
    {
      DateTimeFormatterBuilder fmb = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
      fmb.parseCaseInsensitive();
      fmb.append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM yyyy"));

      DateTimeFormatter formatter = fmb.toFormatter();

      myYM = YearMonth.parse(myInputString.trim(), formatter);
      calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
      calendar.clear();
      calendar.set(myYM.getYear(), myYM.getMonthValue(), 1);
    }
    catch(DateTimeParseException e)
    {
        // Invalid date format
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use java Calendar.

```
public void display(int year, int month){
    Calendar car = Calendar.getInstance();
    car.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    car.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    car.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);      
    print(String.format("%" + 23 + "s", new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/yyyy").format(car.getTime()))+"\n");
    print(String.format("%" + 5 + "s", "Su"));
    print(String.format("%" + 5 + "s", "Mo"));
    print(String.format("%" + 5 + "s", "Tu"));
    print(String.format("%" + 5 + "s", "We"));
    print(String.format("%" + 5 + "s", "Th"));
    print(String.format("%" + 5 + "s", "Fr"));
    print(String.format("%" + 6 + "s", "Sa\n"));
    for(int i=1;i<car.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);i++){
        print(String.format("%" + 5 + "s", ""));
    }
    for(int i = 1;i<=LastDayOfMonth(month, year);i++){
        if(car.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==7){
            print(String.format("%" + 6 + "s", i+"\n"));
        }else{ 
            print(String.format("%" + 5 + "s", i));
        }
        car.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, car.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)+1);
    }
}

public void print(String s){
    System.out.print(s);
}
public boolean isLeapYear(int year){
    return ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0));
}
public int LastDayOfMonth(int month, int year){
    if(month == 1){//February
        if(this.isLeapYear(year))return 29;
        else return 28;
    }else if(month==0||month==2||month==4||month==6||month==7||month==9||month==11){
        return 31;
    }else{
        return 30;
    }
}</p>
```

Note: The first month of the year in the java calendars is JANUARY which is 0.
E.g Calendar of January 2015 `display(2015, 0)`

If you want to validate the date, you can do it before calling the display function.

[image: Result]

Comment: this works great, but i think is out of the specifications.. these are the methods we need to include: public static void displayCalendar
(int month, int year)
public static int getMonthNumber
(String s)

public static int getDaysIn
(int month, int year)
public static boolean isLeapYear
(int year)
public static String getMonthName
(int month)

public static int getStartDay
(int month, int year)

Comment: At this point, Se Song and I have given you plenty of information you can use to finish this project. You'll need to rework our examples a bit to fit your needs. Give it a try. If you have problems you can't solve post back.

Comment: Thank Jim Archer, I have seen your code is working on validated the date already. So, I just wrote the way to display calendar. Maria Andrea Erramouspe thank for your feedback, if you need to validate the date you can check the Jim Archer example. I will complete this if I'm free enough.